# How to update multiple elements of a single array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a document of mongoDb like following

```
{
  _id: "c4bYJWz42T2JzbmHh",
  DATA:[
      {sno:1, name: xyz, country: xyz},
      {sno:2, name: xyz1, country: xyz1},
      {sno:3, name: xyz2, country: xyz2}
  ]
}
```

Now i want to update name and country on basis of 'sno'.I have used this approach

```
ExampleDb.update({
        _id: data.id
      }, {
        $set: {
            "DATA.$[elem].name": data.name ,
            "DATA.$[elem].country" :data.country 
          }
        },
     {
       arrayFilters: [ { "elem.sno": data.sno } ]
     });
```

ut seems worng as it show following error.

```
Exception while invoking method 'ExampleDb.update' MongoError: Modifiers operate on fields but we found a Array instead.
```

Comment: What does `data` contain?

Comment: data is basically a object contain id, name, country and sno key like data = {id : 'c4bYJWz42T2JzbmHh', name :'xyzz', sno: 2, country: ''xyzz }

Comment: typo? data.name and not data.Name

Comment: I correct the question but i need solution as i am getting error @matthPen

Comment: For me its working. Tested with mongo shell